# Deleting roles in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-5, roles

I am trying to delete a Role from my database but it doesn't work , when I click the delete button, the system crashed and the error's message show me this :

It can't find the resource.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: / Roles / Delete

This is the method used in my RoleController.cs to Delete de Role:

```
public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        return View();
    }

 public ActionResult Delete(string RoleName)
    {
        var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        context.Roles.Remove(thisRole);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My view is in my "Role" folder. This is the view used:

```css
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Roles Listing </h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Create New Role", "Create") | @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Role", "ManageUserRoles")
<hr />
<div>
    @foreach (var role in Model)
    {
        <p>
            <strong>@role.Name | </strong>
            <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
            <a href="/Roles/Delete?RoleName=@role.Name" class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a>
            </span> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { roleName = @role.Name })
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

What can I do?

Edit (12/05/2015) :

My RouteConfig.cs is this:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your routing. Also know that Delete is tricky to get right in routing. I typically avoid using it to avoid HTTP DELETE confusion. Also, why did you tag this as MVC 4 and then say you're in MVC 5?

Comment: You really should not have actions that cause changes to your data be Get operations, since this can be abused by hackers.  They need only create an image tag that includes the url to delete your own user group as the src, as soon as you view the image.. boom, bad things happen.  Any action that causes changes to your system should be a POST or orther non-GET operation.

Comment: Check what is the HTML generated by this section `<span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
            <a href="/Roles/Delete?RoleName=@role.Name" class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a>
            </span>` of your view. I suppose the RoleName is not appended properly to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that your routing configuration is incorrect.

Have you created a route for it?

Looking at it, I'm guessing here.. Your url should actually be "Role/Delete" on a your hyperlink, as your trying to find it by "Roles/Delete" it probably wont find it.

Without seeing your RouteConfig.cs its hard to say.

EDIT.

Instead of this :-

```
<a href="/Roles/Delete?RoleName=@role.Name" class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a>
```

Try this

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("Delete","Role", new { rolename = @Model.Name })' class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I have added my RouteConfig.cs in the question but I don't know what I can do.

Comment: Updated my Answer, give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

use HttpPost and HttpGet attribute for your actions

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string RoleName)
{
    var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

    context.Roles.Remove(thisRole);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The [HttpPost] attribute tells the routing engine to send any POST requests to that action method.